# How to fix Typescript ReferenceError Class not defined when importing class as type

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm using the typescript with the eslint rule `@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports` which requires me to import types as types (`import type { InputType }...`).

However when I do that with an exported es6 class, say `Car`, (`import type { Car } from './models'`) I get the error:

`ReferenceError: Car is not defined`

`Car` is a class exported from `car.model.ts` as follows:

```
export class Car {
...
}
```

Please how do I fix this?

I use the following packages:

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.31.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.31.0",
"ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
"typescript": "^4.4.2"
```

My ./tsconfig.json is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2019",
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./src/types/*",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

My nodejs version

`"node": "^12.13.1"`

Comment: Share your code please where you have written the code of *Car* and exported it.

Comment: Hi @ShakirAqeel, thanks. I just updated the question. Car is simply an es6 class exported as `export class Car {}`

Comment: I think you are giving an incorrect path of the file, the correct path is import type { Car } from './models/car.model.ts'